# getting claims from IdentityServer resource scope

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, identityserver3, identityserver2

I am having trouble getting IdentityServer to return any claims on a resource scope. I define the resource scope as:

```
    private static Scope Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return new Scope
            {
                Name = "roles",
                DisplayName = "Roles",
                Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                    new ScopeClaim(SecurityContants.ClaimTypes.Role)
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private static Scope Api
    {
        get
        {
            return new Scope
            {
                Name = "api",
                DisplayName = "Api",
                IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
            //i've also tried adding the claim directly
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = false
            };
        }
    }
```

Then they're added to a collection and handed back. 
In my API Startup.cs, I configure owin like:

```
public void Configuration (IAppBuilder app)
    {

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
                new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
                {                        
                    Authority = "http://localhost/security.tokenserver.site",
                    RequiredScopes = new[] { "api", "roles" },
                    RoleClaimType = "roles"
                });
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

My API endpoint is simply:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var claims = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in user.Claims)
        {
            claims.Add(item.Value);
        }
        return claims;
    }
```

The output of this, when called from my UI after authenticating is:

```
[ "customer_svc", "api", "https://idsrv3/embedded", "https://idsrv3/embedded/resources", "1448048492", "1448044892" ]
```

So the initial login at the UI works (i see the roles claim there), retrieving the token works, and handing the token up to the API works. But I cannot see the user's roles after the token is handed back up to the API.

What am I missing?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in IdentityServer3. I'm not the only one with the issue: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2240